# Popup notification on locked mobile device for new questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, notifications, mobile

Sometimes pretty randomly (like waiting in line, etc.) I have a moment to look at the new questions on my mobile phone. But it is inefficient to constantly monitor your phone. It'd be much better to have a notification on mobile devices to immediately pop up when a new question is posted, similarly to how, for instance, email, Twitter, etc. work on mobile phones. I have iPhone, but imagine Android works pretty much alike. I use [this Stack Exchange app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723) but it does not seem to have a feature of sending a notification popup on a locked phone for new questions. **Have anyone accomplished this or have some experience / thoughts to share? Perhaps some other apps are able to do this?** Thanks!

#### Update

One of simple solutions is RSS feeder, as was kindly suggested by @Glorfindel in his answer below. It'd be nice if anyone can recommend good RSS feeder that works solidly with the new questions feed from MSE giving more or less timely popup notification on locked mobile device.

Comment: Would be nice if Mathematica had integration with some push notification provider for `SendMessage` and server-side `ScheduledTask`s that have a periodicity of less than an hour ;)

Answer (score 5):

I have such a system, but I made it complicated and it's not something that really scales out to other users. You see part of it in action [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318926/295232); notifications are shared between my iPhone and Apple Watch. There, it is hooked up to one of [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/)'s WebSockets, for getting notified of potential spam posts; I also use it to monitor new questions in certain tags across the website, via Stack Exchange's own WebSockets which are documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/295232). For example, all new questions on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) or new chess-themed puzzles on [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). All those feeds are hardcoded into the server, and I need an active Apple Developer Program to install the app on my smartphone. Perhaps it would be easier on Android.

It's probably much easier to connect one of [Stack Exchange's RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3403/295232) to a service like [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com/if_notifications), but I think there is a delay of a few minutes in the RSS feed. WebSockets are real-time; it's the same technique that gives you the '1 new question' banner on the homepage.

Here are some similar requests on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Trilogy Addicts - Get "real-time" notifications of new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44545/295232)
- [Receive notifications on all answers, comments and new questions for a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172638/295232)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, many nice ideas! For simple solution I also was thinking about RRS feeder and a few minutes delay won't matter that much for me. I will add update in my question.